# Query RxJava2 Db into another subject

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

On my Android project I'm heavily relying on [RxJava2](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava), [SqlBrite](https://github.com/square/sqlbrite)(with RxJavaInterop) and [SqlDelight](https://github.com/square/sqldelight).

I got one rx stream that is supposed to go indefinitely (until my service stops) and on it I have a `.flatMap` of `Function<String, ObservableSource<Action>>`.

Meaning, this `flatMap` contains a `Subject<Action>`, will receive `String actionId`, do some (irrelevant for the question) processing on those actionId, and depending on condition should query the database for the `Action` object and dispatch it to the `subject`

My first approach was to do the query directly:

```
Cursor c = db.query(...);
if(c.moveFirst()) {
    Action a = Action.SELECT_ALL_MAPPER.map(c);
    subject.onNext(selectAll);
}
```

But this blocks the running thread and I rather trigger this on its own stream that should do the following:

- query (should return 0 or 1 item)
- if there's a value: map to `Action` object and push the value to the `subject`
- if there's no value: terminate/dispose.
- the `subject` cannot receive terminate or error. It must stay alive for future events.

My current approach is the following code:

```
RxJavaInterop.toV2Observable(db.createQuery(
    Action.TABLE_NAME,
    Action.FACTORY.Select_by_id(actionId).statement)
    .mapToOne(new Func1<Cursor, Action>() {
        @Override public Action call(Cursor cursor) {
            return Action.SELECT_ALL_MAPPER.map(cursor);
        }
    }))
    .take(1)
    .subscribe(new Consumer<Action>() {
        @Override public void accept(Action action) throws Exception {
            subject.onNext(action);
        }
    });
```

And although this seems to do the trick on the first impression, I see a few errors on it:

- I can't dispose it. Even if I get the reference to Disposable object, I cannot call it from inside `Consumer<Action>` because it "might have not been initialised" (which I understand the reason, it's OK).
- if there's no action with the given ID, the observable will hang in there for ever, until the VM is killed.

**So the question:**

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

> I rather trigger this on its own stream

Take a look at [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid). This could look like:

```
yourRxStream
    .flatMap(*db request here*)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subcribe(subject);
```

---

> the `subject` cannot receive terminate or error. It must stay alive for
>   future events.

Switch the Subject with a [Relay](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay):

> Subjects are useful to bridge the gap between non-Rx APIs. However,
>   they are stateful in a damaging way: when they receive an `onComplete`
>   or `onError` they no longer become usable for moving data. This is the
>   observable contract and sometimes it is the desired behavior. Most
>   times it is not.
>
> Relays are simply Subjects without the aforementioned property. They
>   allow you to bridge non-Rx APIs into Rx easily, and without the worry
>   of accidentally triggering a terminal state.

---

Finally for the request than could output 0 or 1 item, use a [Maybe](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#maybe).

Comment: Relay is a good idea and I'll check on it. But the 0 or 1 unfortunately it doesn't solve with your suggestion. RxJava2 does not accept `null` and it directly throws NPE. Also, the observable DB request is created by sqlbrite library, which stays open/updating until disposed. So I need to dispose or maybe timeout to shut it down as I need only that 1-off event and then wait for the next `actionId` which will be a new query. Thanks for effort thou.

Comment: Since you can't send null, I was thinking about writing a basic monad to wrap the item or absence of it into a class, that could be called Maybe. Then I remembered that Maybe already exist as an Observable alternative. Since it's just the perfect fit, I updated my answer.